# Encryption using AES 256 and SHA-2

Tags: java, encryption

I have a situation where I need to first encrypt a message using a public key and vector, that is already provided. Also as per requirement I need to use SHA-2 as well. For now, I am assuming that I need to hash the encrypted message and then send to the server. I have two questions related to this
1. Is it wise to hash the encrypted message? Also, will sending the encrypted message and hashed value to the server be a good idea?
2. I have done a lot search on internet, but whenever I try to get some example of using AES 256 and SHA-2 together, I actually land up where the difference between the two is explained. Can any help me with some sample code?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: "Use SHA-2" for what? You need to explain in a lot more detail what this is for and what the specific requirements are. Neither AES nor SHA-2 involves public keys.

Comment: Actually I have been given a Encryption key and a vector key, and using AES 256 , I need to encrypt some user specific data, example: UserId, and then send to a weblogic server.what I am trying to ask is that, can I use SHA-2 hashing technique to hash the encrypted value, UserID, and then pass both the hash and the encrypted value to server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the stuff first.

## Public Key Cryptography

Allows a given pair (*Kpriv*, *Kpub*) to be used on a cipher to encrypt and decrypt data.
Any data encrypted with *Kpriv* can only be decrypted with *Kpub* and any data encrypted with *Kpub* can only be decrypted with *Kpriv*.

A nice and well known example of a public key cipher is **RSA**.

Asymmetric cryptography requires extremely large keys in order to be secure, such that it's **extremely** slow to execute! You should never encrypt large amount of data with Asymetric keys cryptography. You can use it in the beginning of a connecition to exchange a symetric key *Ks*, though.

## Symetric Key Cryptography

Allows a *Ks* to be used on a cipher to encrypt and decrypt data.

An example of a symetric cipher is **AES**. AES is in fact so versatile you can change lots of parameters, such as, (as you mention) the *Blocksize* which can be of 128, 192 or 256 bits. **AES256** is the AES cipher configured with a blocksize of 256 bits.

The block size is what's used against the provided *Ks* to perform the actual encryption. Note that your data can be larger than the block size (the algorithm will still work, It'l simply reuse the same *Ks*). Simply reusing the key every block is known as *ECB* mode and can reveal patterns if your data is repetitive. An alternative is to use modes like *CBC* or *CTR* which rely on also using previous block data and XORing with the next block data, to eliminate such patterns. What mode should you use depends on your data.

Note that, according to your cipher mode, you eventually will need *padding*. I'm assuming you are already quite familiar with this terms when you asked that question.

## Guarantees By Cryptography

Cryptography does guarantee that the encrypted data is confidential but that's just it. It does not give any other guarantees such as whether the data is authentic or whether it has been tampered with or not.

While tampering data will most likely result in unintelligible text even after decryption, in cryptography, there's no such thing as invalid plaintext. As such, you need some mechanism to know if your data is valid or not.

A secure hash algorithm such as *SHA* can help you know whether your decrypted data is valid or not.

However, for these purposes, you usually shouldn't directly use a Digest algorithm. Try to instead use a **MAC**. That MAC can use *SHA256* algorithm but MAC's and Hashes are not exactly the same.

## How To Do It In Practice

If all you want is confidentiality and tampering detection, you would use the cipher and digest (or hash) algorithm as such:

**E ks ( SHA(data) || data )**

Where *E* is a symmetric cipher, **ks** is the shared symmetric key, *SHA(data)* is the digest of data using a secure hash algorithm, *||* means concatenation and *data* is a byte array.

A more safer approach would be:
**E ks ( MAC mk(data) || data )**

Where *mk* is the MAC's secret key.

Now just search how to "java symetric cipher" and "java hash byte array" and use the two as I'm describing above.